# Linux mint 12: change default editor and terminal

Tags: gnome, terminal, linux-mint, editors

I have the sublime text editor located in `usr/bin`. How can I make it the default editor so I can do `sublime /var/www/test.php`?

And can I change the default terminal to `yakuake`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without setting it as the default, `sublime /var/www/test.php` should work (as long as `/usr/bin` is in your `PATH` and `sublime` has the executable bit set). To set the default program for something, look at the documentation for `update-alternatives`.

Comment: I know how to change the default editor terminal now, just one more question what is the default permission of `/usr/bin` i changed the permission so that i can paste sublime into that folder and now that it's done, i would like to reset the default permission

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou The directory and files are usually `rwxr-xr-x`.